# ReactDataGrid - Filter not working on particular column when its cell values are passed as DOM instead of strings

Tags: reactjs, react-data-grid

I am using React-data-grid with Filter options in the table. For some column cells, i am passing a DOM object (not as a string). And for this column, the filter functionality is not working.

```
       this._columns = [
        {
            key: 'date',
            name: 'Shipment date',
            width: 220,
            sortable: true,
            filterable: true,
        },{
            key: 'price',
            name: 'Shipment Price',
            width: 220,
            sortable: true,
            filterable: true,
        }];
```

And here are the Rows...

```
    let rows = [];
    _.each(response, function(value, index){
    rows.push({
            date: value.date
            price: <div>{value.currencySymbol} <span>{value.price}</span></div>
           })
    });
```

So, this is my Column Metadata , and Rows. I am passing this metadata to ReactDataGrid Component.
**Now the** `date` **filter is working fine.** However this `price` filter is not working well due to this inline DOM element.

Can Someone please help me to get this solved?

Answer (score 0):

Resolved this by using '`formatter`'  or else we could use '`getRowMetaData`'

formatter: an adaptor/middleware for rendering the value in DOM
getRowMetaData: it is used to get the adjacent cell values of the row. And, We could achieve using props.dependentValues where it will have all the column data of the row. I used this in 'Shipment Price' column, to get the other column values of that row.

```
this._columns = [
        {
            key: 'date',
            name: 'Shipment date',
            width: 220,
            sortable: true,
            filterable: true,
            formatter: (props)=>(<div style={{border: '0px'}}>{props.value}</div>),
        },{
            key: 'price',
            name: 'Shipment Price',
            width: 220,
            sortable: true,
            filterable: true,
            formatter: (props) => (this.getTrackingUrl(props.dependentValues.rawObj, props.dependentValues.indexVal)),
            getRowMetaData: (row) => (row)
        }];
```

Comment: note: `formatter` no longer works in latest version. `renderCell` will render custom HTML, but doesn't allow searching.